# What does it mean if input impedance given as a current regulator?

Tags: datasheet, current-source, input-impedance

[This](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/140b/0900766b8140b509.pdf) SSR relay has an input impedance given in its datasheet as:

[image]

It says "Nominal Input Impedance is a current regulator". At 5V 16mA.

But how can I model this type of input impedance? I will use 12V input but there is no info that I can estimate the current or input impedance.

Does that mean whatever voltage applied it will regulate the current to around 16mA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input terminals appear to be the *control* terminals that require (typical) 16mA to operate independent of input voltage within the specified range.

This is not unexpected as the switching elements are [SCRs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60576/can-i-use-a-silicon-controlled-rectifier-to-discharge-a-capacitor) that are isolated from the input, which require a certain amount of gate current to maintain the ON state.

The output terminals are the relay contacts and the output terminal current will be load dependent.